# Laravel - Vue chunk upload - Frontend and Backend example

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I use Laravel 5.5 and I tried to use [Pion chunk upload](https://packagist.org/packages/pion/laravel-chunk-upload) to upload large files. I followed the steps and I think backend should work. The problem is that I am unable to make work the frontend uploader. I want to use a vue component for this task and I tried several of them, but the most promising was the [Simple Uploader](https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader).

Can someone show me a full example of these two working together?